# Does Mark-and-sweep algorithm work only with references?

Tags: javascript, browser, garbage-collection, mark-and-sweep

It's not entirely clear to me how **Mark-and-sweep** algorithm works.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#mark-and-sweep_algorithm)

> This algorithm reduces the definition of "an object is no longer needed" to "an object is unreachable".

It turns out that this algorithm works only with references on objects and doesn't clear global variables, functions... at all. Does it?

Comment: A global variable is per definition reachable. What condition shall justify the sudden disappearance of a global variable?

Comment: @Holger I see, so it's just about references on objects